# particular eloquent query in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

```
Bookmaker table
id

user table
id

Bookmaker_user table
id
user_id
bookmaker_id    

transaction table
id
name
bookmaker_user_id
```

I want to display all the transactions name `where user_id=3` using `Eloquent` if possible. Which relation to use? `HasManyThrough`?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to setup the tables? Anyway, you need a model for your pivot table `bookmaker_user` and then `user hasManyThrough(Transaction,BookmakerUser)`

Comment: maybe add user_id in transaction table, its more efficient? thx anyway

Comment: Well, I don't know. But I would guess that transaction is a link between `user` and `bookmaker`, so maybe yuo don't need that transaction table at all? Depends on your needs.

Comment: ok , and with query builder ?

Comment: I already gave you solution in my first comment.